# How to change which water conditioner I'm using

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, water-parameters, water-changes, shrimp

I have two tanks: my ghost shrimp tank is using Tetra AquaSafe for Bettas water conditioner (the tank used to also contain a Betta fish, but no longer does). My Betta tank is using Seachem Prime water conditioner (truthfully, largely because I find it more convenient to work with, since it's much more concentrated).

I was considering switching the shrimp tank to use Seachem Prime too (so that I don't have to stock two separate water conditioners).

Are there any special considerations for how to make the switch, or can I just start using Prime at the next water change?

Comment: Why do you use conditioners anyway? (I am just curious, not sarcastic) If the tanks are properly set and cycled, you do not need them. For de-chlorinating the tap water, you only need a bucket. Put the water in the bucket, no lid, and wait about 2 days. The chlorine goes away, you can safely use the water. You can cheaply (?) buy a water filter, which will provide clean water both for you and for your tank. With a reverse osmosis filter, you get incredibly clean water.

Comment: @virolino speaking as someone who uses conditioners, leaving a bucket of water sitting out is only practical in limited circumstances (small tank, minimal water changes, sufficient space, sufficient pre-planning, no other animals/children/adults to interfere with it or be endangered by it). There is no way I could simply "leave out" enough water when doing a change on my large tank, as even excluding the other animals in the household, I do not have space to set out 6-8 buckets.

Answer (score 3):

You simply stop using one and start using the other; the only thing you need to do is to follow the instructions.

To be totally safe do not change all of the water at once; do partial water changes so the change of dechlorinator is gradual.

Most likely, they both contains the same basic chemicals, only in different concentration--the differences is mostly in the additives. As long as both contain dechlorinator, you should be safe. You will still have to do weekly water tests and do the usual maintenance of your tank(s).

Some additional information about chlorine and chloramine in tap water: Chlorine will outgas from the tap water if you store it in an open container overnight. Chloramine, on the other hand, takes a lot more time to outgas, so unless you store the water in an open container for a week, you will need to use a dechlorinator.

Source https://www.thesprucepets.com/remove-chloramines-from-tap-water-2924183